# Different travel dates in D-Tier 4 (General) Dep. Partner and D-Tier 4 (General) Dep Child VISA

Tags: visas, uk, passports

My wife and daughter had applied for UK Tier-4 Dependent VISA. VISA has been granted but the allowed date in their VISA differs due to which my daughter, who is just four and half years old, cannot travel with her mother. My wife got visa for the date earlier than she intended to travel but my daughter received for the planned date. Both the applications had the same date filled in the travel information section of the visa form. Though we received documents today, my wife's visa has just 20 days validity today onward as it has earlier issue date. What should I do in this context?